# Android ImageView drawing cache is null even after layout

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a self cropping image view I'm using with the drawing cache.  I'm using the ViewTreeObserver to see when the layout is ready then taking the cropped image in the view and updating the ImageView's bitmap with the cropped version.  The drawing cache is null every time.  I can set the ImageView's bitmap drawable to getDrawingCache() and it's fine, but horrible on memory.  I'm trying to just take that snapshot and release everything else for GC.  What am I missing here?

```
    public CroppingImageView(Context context){
        super(context);

        ViewTreeObserver vto = getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                crop();

            }
        });
    }

    public void crop(){

        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap cached = getDrawingCache();
        Log.i("ImageView", "drawing cache " + getDrawingCache());
        Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cached);
        destroyDrawingCache();
        cached.recycle();
        cached = null;
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);

    }
```

Comment: Why do you have `setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);` ?

Comment: Not being sarcastic.  Legitimately asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the ViewTreeObserver and did my cropping onLayout and now everything seems to be working ok.

```
protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom){
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    crop();
}
```